# Stream Azure container logging to web app

Tags: azure, kubernetes, logging, stream

I wish to extend my web app's functionality with the possibility to show the results of a custom Azure logging query like this:

```
let apiIds = KubePodInventory
    | where ServiceName == "my-service-name"
    | distinct ContainerID;
ContainerLog
| where ContainerID in (apiIds)
    and LogEntry contains ("my custom query")
| order by TimeGenerated desc 
| project TimeGenerated, LogEntry
```

A great addition would be to have live logging also.

However, I have no idea where to get started. Is there somebody with (good/bad) experience with this idea?

Comment: You can use the Azure Monitor Query SDK in your app https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/monitor/Azure.Monitor.Query

Comment: Great! That was exactly what I needed for querying.

Comment: @silent are you also aware of solutions to connect to a live logging stream? I managed to have it working using the `kubectl logs -f` command, but that's not what you want.

Comment: no, that would need to be something that connects directly to k8s, not just Azure monitor

Comment: And I used https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp for live logs. Great stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(as discussed in the comments)

You can use the Azure Monitor Query SDK in your app https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/monitor/Azure.Monitor.Query